# Ajax refresh block with templater

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i need refresh page after POST ajax submit. 
Try this, but not successful

```
    function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "engine/modules/eshop_cart.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#result").html(html);  
            }  
        });  
    }
function addCart(){
    var price = $("#price_id").text();
    var name = $("#name_id").text();
$.post(
  "engine/ajax/eshop_cart.php",
  {
    price: price,
    name: name
  },
  onAjaxSuccess
);
}
function onAjaxSuccess(data)
{

show();

}
```

File engine/modules/eshop_cart:

```
$myip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."_shop_cart WHERE ip='$myip'");
while($row = $db->get_row($select)){
$tpl->load_template("eshop/cartitems.tpl");
$tpl->set("{r_name}", $row["name"]);
$tpl->set("{r_price}", $row["price"]);
$tpl->set("{r_count}", $row["count"]);
$tpl->compile("cartlist");
$tpl->clear();
}
$tpl->load_template("eshop/cart.tpl");
$tpl->set("{old_cart}", $tpl->result["cartlist"]);
$tpl->compile("cart");
$tpl->clear();
```

If im use my code, after POST submit block with id = result are null.
in terms of bollean.. Help and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Try This ...

```
 function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "engine/modules/eshop_cart.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#result").html(html);  
                location.reload();
            }  
        });  
    }
```